# Problem of Permutation and combination

Tags: combinatorics

What are the number of ways to fill $n$ places with $3$ distinct objects, such that each of the objects appear at least once in the arrangement, assuming we have infinite supply of each of the objects ($n\ge3$).

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Inclusion Exclusion would appear relevant here.

Comment: My thought is that we first select 3 places out of n so nC3*(3!)*(3^(n-3)). I think that in this some cases will repeat. How to overcome that

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea.   Try it for $n=4$, for instance.   Inclusion Exclusion is better.

Comment: I am not able to get how to use Inclusion exclusion. Can you please help. For n=4 the answer is simple=36 i think.

Comment: Note: it's a good idea to work this out for small $n$, no matter what.  For $n=4,5$, say, it's easy enough to do by hand, and it will give you some good checks against your eventual formula.

Comment: This is a completely standard problem in Inclusion Exclusion.  Any discussion of that method should include examples pretty much the same as this.  Start by counting the arrangements without the restriction, then correct for the cases which violate the restriction.

Comment: hey @lulu I am kinda new contributor too , I have answered below , is that correct ?

Comment: @KartikBhatia No, it isn't.  It is a good start, but you neglect the cases in which only one object appears.  That is, you correctly subtract off the cases where one specified object is missing, but then you need to add back the cases where two specified objects are miss

Comment: sorry for that ! I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your answer
Let us first find all possibilities, We can keep any of three objects at each position so for the N positions you will have

$3*3*3*3....$ ***n*** times => $3^n $
Now in all these $3^n$ possibilities we have not considered cases where Each object should be present atleast Once .
***For doing this part Let's Subtract the cases where they do not appear at All***
So  If We do not include some object You will be left with $2$ other objects to fill so For removing each of them You will have $2^n$ Possiblities with you, and you try it out for all the three objects then you have $ 3*2^n $ cases where one of them does not appear at all. 
So the final result is $ 3^n - 3*2^n $.

Comment: you can read more about principle of inclusion and exclusion. Answer should be $3^{n}-3\times 2^{n} + 3\times 1^{n}$

Comment: to expand on @RezhaAdrianTanuharja's comment: your solution, as written, replaces the naive overcount with an undercount, because you are subtracting off solutions with only one type of object multiple times (e.g., if the three types of object are red, green, and blue, then the "all-red" configuration gets subtracted off in the count of "no-blue" configurations and then gets subtracted off again in the count of "no-green" configurations.)

Comment: My bad  btw Thanks :) I will edit my answer